# Prove $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!\sqrt{k}}x^k $ defines a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, power-series, uniform-convergence

Prove $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!\sqrt{k}}x^k$$ defines a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

I think we can show that if  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!\sqrt{k}}x^k $ is uniformly convergent $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, then it defines a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

We could say that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!\sqrt{k}}x^k \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}x^k $$

And show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}x^k$ converges pointwise by the ratio test, so $f(x)$ must converge pointwise. But how would I show uniform convergence? If I show uniform convergence, there's a theorem that lets me say that uniform limits of continuous functions are continuous (thus $f(x)$ is continuous.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It suffices to show uniform convergence on any interval $[x-1,x+1]$. ($f$ is continuous iff $f$ is continuous at any point $x$.)

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: See my edit. (Note the convergence is not uniform on all of $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: For any power series, would it be sufficient to show uniform converge on the interval you stated above? Or does it just apply to this example?

Comment: You might need to change the interval, so that it actually inside the interval of convergence.

Comment: Are you familiar with Weierstrass $M$-test? Using it an estimate similar to the one you gave shows that the series is uniformly continuous on any interval of the form $[-a,a]$, where $a$ is an arbitrary positive constant. Do you see how you get continuity everywhere from that?

Comment: We have a theorem which I think is similar to it. It is "Suppose $R>0$ and let $(a_n)_{n\in N}$ be a sequence of numbers. Suppose $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |(a_n)|R^n <\infty$ (Converges). Then $f_N (x) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n$ converges uniformly on $[-R,R]$ (Note: this theorem implies $f$ is continuous by a previous theorem).

Comment: So, apply that to show $f$ is continuous at any (fixed point) $x$.

Comment: So if we fix $x$, we need to show $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\frac{1}{k!\sqrt{k}}| R^n$ converges?

Comment: With $R>|x|$, yes.

Comment: Do you mean $R\leq |x|$? Converges uniformly on $[-R,R]$?

Comment: Wait. No you're correct. $x\in [-R,R]$ so $|x|$ $\leq R$

Comment: So if we show it converges for $R>0$, it must converge uniformly for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$? And by the previous theorem in our notes, it is continuous?

Comment: Is the theorem I'm using the Weierstrass $M$-test?

Comment: It does *not* converge uniformly on $\Bbb R$. But, given $R>0$, it does converge uniformly on $[-R,R]$ by the result in one of your previous comments (which is essentially the $M$-test). Thus for any $R>0$, $f$ is continuous on $[-R,R]$. This implies $f$ is continuous at each  $x\in\Bbb R$; thus, continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Excellent. If you can put your explanation as an answer, I will be able to mark this question as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series does not converge uniformly on $\Bbb R$.

But, given $R>0$, it does converge uniformly on $[−R,R]$, by the result mentioned in one of your previous comments above (which is essentially the M-test).

Thus for any $R>0$, $f$ is continuous on $[−R,R]$  (for reasons mentioned at the end of your post). This implies $f$ is continuous at each $x\in\Bbb R$; and thus, $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Condensed version: You need to show $f$ is continuous at each fixed $x\in \Bbb R$. This will follow if you can show the convergence is uniform on any set of the form $[-R,R]$, $R>0$.

Answer (score 1):

For a shorter argument (requires more knowledge though), we may say that we're dealing with a power series with infinite radius of convergence (use ratio test to prove this).

But a power series converges uniformly over any compact set included in the open disk of convergence.

It is therefore continous on any compact subset of $\mathbb R$, hence continuous at any point in $\mathbb R$.